# Auditing DDL with MySQL

Tags: mysql, audit, iseries

We have a MySQL database on an IBM i (as/400) that has many people with admin access. We would like to audit who is making changes, and when they are made. On SQL Server we would use DDL Triggers, but [those don't exist on MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=2418). There is a counter proposal to do this via CREATE EVENT, but that is also unimplemented.

What options do I have to monitor DDL? Most people are using MySQL admin. I'm using MySQL Workbench, and inside the network, and inside the network all parties have direct access to the MySQL database because Microsoft Access accesses it via linked tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a license for enterprise edition, upgrade to 5.5 or 5.7 and use the [audit log plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/audit-log-plugin.html).

Comment: Can you give some more meat to your answer? As written it feels more like a comment than an answer. It might be helpful to expand on "audit log plugin."

Comment: (1) he needs to consider whether to upgrade, and (2) he needs to study the docs on such plugins.  I think this is a case where "go see X" is a sufficient answer.

Comment: Ok if you feel this answer is as good as it can possibly be then that is your prerogative.

Comment: Upon a cursory glance, it seems that this is backported to 55, but that it requires an Enterprise license. Therefore, its a good option, but not an option in this environment.